# Android Java : Efficient redrawing bitmap for game?

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I am getting allocations in my game loop because I use Bitmap.createBitmap for each frame of my 16 frame bitmap animation like so:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap;

public init(){
for(int j=0;j<16;j++)
    {
        Bitmap pick2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), getResources().getIdentifier("walk"+j, "drawable", packageName), shipOptions);

        walkArray.add(pick2);
    }
}

onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap);
}

final Runnable walkData = new Runnable()
{
    public void run(){
        try{    
        if(walkAnim==true)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(walkArray.get(walkNum), 0, 0, walkArray.get(walkNum).getWidth(), walkArray.get(walkNum).getHeight(), matrix, true);
                walkNum++;
                if(walkNum>15)
                {
                    walkNum=0;
                }
                invalidate();
            }
            if(walkAnim==false)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pick, 0, 0, pick.getWidth(),
                        pick.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            }

        handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
};
```

I'm not too worried about how fast the runnable is called, I am more worried about the size of the allocations being up to 300kb.  Is there any way I can optimize this code?  I would like to avoid using imageviews and use a canvsas if possible.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand bitmap caching and efficient bitmap drawing.  if someone could point me in the right direction it would help me a lot :)

Comment: I found this video extremely helpful, if anyone ever reads this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8